# Dell Idrac Keyboard does not work after ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade

Tags: keyboard, 13.10

The upgrade failed and i cannot type at the console. I tried booting from the 13.10 installation media and the keyboard does not work there as well. Is there a known issue with the dell idrac and 13.10? i have used it with all previous versions to date. It is a dell r720

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

to your kernel commandline parameters from the Grub menu and it should work. Something to do with the power management putting the iDrac fake keyboard to sleep.